# How to remove git under xcode path

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I've 2 installed versions of git on my osx. 
One of them under

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core
```

And the other one is under brew directory. I want to use the latest version which is under brew directory.
How should i remove first one and switch to latest for using ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. I just removed git-core under `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec`

Comment: That's a terrible idea. Don't do that! It'll break version control features in Xcode, and will be reverted when Xcode is updated.

Comment: Make sure that `usr/local/bin` which is used by home-brew is high in your $PATH so that the brew version is used in preference to the Xcode version.